# Importing from another directory

Tags: python, import, directory, pythonpath, package-managers

I am structuring my Python application with the following folder architecture (roughly following the outline [here](http://guide.python-distribute.org/creation.html)):

```
myapp:
    myapp_service1:
        myapp_service1_start.py
        ...
    myapp_service2:
        myapp_service2_start.py
        ...
    myapp_service3:
        myapp_service3_start.py
        ...
    common:
        myapp_common1.py
        myapp_common2.py
        myapp_common3.py
        ...
scripts:
    script1.py
    script2.py
    script3.py
    ...
tests:
    ...
docs:
    ...
LICENSE.txt
MANIFEST.in
README
```

This is ideal file/folder hierarchy for me, however, I am confused on how to reference modules from outside folders. For instance, `myapp_service1_start.py` needs to reference function in `myapp_common1.py` and `myapp_common2.py`.

I know I need to somehow add reference to the system `path` or `pythonpath`, but I'm not sure the best way to do this in code. Or rather where I would even do this in code.

**How can I do this?**

I've seen a lot of posts about creating a full Python package to be *installed* via `pip`, but this seems like overkill to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to make each of your `myapp_service*_start.py` files add `myapp/` directory to `sys.path`.

For example, drop a file called `import_me.py` into `myapp_service1/` with code that appends the "one up" directory (relative to importing file) to `sys.path`:

```
import os
import sys
import inspect
this_dir = os.path.dirname(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe()))
src_dir = os.path.join(this_dir, '..')
sys.path.insert(0, src_dir)
```

Then, in your `myapp_service1_start.py` you can do something like:

```
import import_me
from common import myapp_common1
from common import myapp_common2
```

Of course, be sure to make `common` directory a Python package by dropping a (possibly empty) `__init__.py` file into it.