# Import from another directory

Tags: python, import, directory

I need to import .py file from another one in another directory (import app2 from app1)
So there is directory tree

```
app:
    dir1:
        app1.py
    dir2:
        app2.py
```

My problem is almost like [Importing from another directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21437126/importing-from-another-directory), but this solution doesnt work for me for some reason

Furthermore i've been trying to do like this (app1.py)

```
from ..dir2 import app2
```

The error is:
Attempted relative import beyond top-level package

How can i solve this?

Comment: The problem was that i didn't put `__init__.py` file into directory from which i want to import. Close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your additional directories to the system path

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/path/to/app1/dir2")
sys.path.insert(0, "/path/to/app2/dir2")
```

Comment: It doesnt work
app2: 
`import sys

sys.path.insert(0, '/myapp/dir1')

from dir1 import app1`
Unable to import dir1

Comment: You may need to move back up one layer in the directory tree. sys.path is the way to add directories for python to search ahead of the system directories in /usr/lib and /usr/share/lib and /usr/local/lib.

Comment: i had tryed `from ..dir2 import app2`, but result is the same: cannot import