# import models from another directory

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm new in Django.
i am following a tutorial and now i have a problem .

[my directory tree is like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ud6jh.png)

and in /pages/views i have this

```
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    from django.shortcuts import render
    
    def home_view(*args, **kwargs):
        return "<h1>Hello world</h1>"
```

and in trydjango/urls i have this

```
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.urls import path

    from pages.views import home_view

    urlpatterns = [
        path('', home_view, name='home'),
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    ]
```

***but it can't recognize pages ***
i also tried these
[solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58049124/import-from-another-directory)
but didn't work!what do i missing?
even i added these codes to settings.py

```
import os
import sys
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
sys.path.append(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'pages'))
```

{ django 3.1 }

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot to create a urls.py file inside the 'pages' app.

in trydjango/urls.py you have to include the urls of the app:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('pages/', include('pages.urls'), name="pages"),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Then create the pages/urls.py file and it should work:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', home_view, name='home'),
]
```

note; dont forget to add 'pages' in the installed_apps inside your settings.py file.